# Swagger API doc from Lumen REST API

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, lumen, swagger-php

I have my API in lumen 8.* As my annotations are getting longer, I want to put all of them into a single or multiple yamls so that my codes get clean.

The package that I'm using is https://github.com/DarkaOnLine/SwaggerLume

Any solution for this?